# Bash Substring File Completion

Tags: substring, tab-completion, bash-completion, zsh-completion

Does bash partial/substring file completion similar to what zsh does?

That is, instead of requiring the user to enter a *prefix* of the filename, then tab; the user can also enter a *substring* of the filename, then tab.

Say a directory contains a file `abcdef`, then not only would `ab<tab>` complete to this filename, but also `bc<tab>` and `cd<tab>` and so on.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague; please provide more detail.  But the answer is probably yes.

Comment: kinda like hitting the TAB 1 time, or twice for a list of alternatives?

Comment: I've clarified the question and explained how does zsh do substring completion.  Hope that was helpful and allows to answer the question better.

Answer (score 3):

If a directory contains the file `abcdef`, then you can enter `*bc*` and then hit the `TAB` key, and it will complete.  Of course, zsh can do it without the `*`, so it's not the same thing.